# Joomla 2.5 filter, sort and pagination combination

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've developed a Joomla frontend data table with paging, filtering and sorting.
Pagination works. Column sort alone works too.

But as example when I sort a column by name, and then go to page 2 (or any other) it shows me the chosen page without the sort. The sort has just disappeared. This is the same for every column.

I derived my model class from JModelList and my PopulateState Method is below.

```
protected function populateState($ordering = 'ordering', $direction = 'DESE')
    {
        // Initialise variables.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $filter_order = JRequest::getCmd('filter_order');
        $filter_order_Dir = JRequest::getCmd('filter_order_Dir');
        $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');

        $this->setState('filter_order', $filter_order);
        $this->setState('filter_order_Dir', $filter_order_Dir);
        $this->setState('filter.search', $search);

        parent::populateState();
    }
```

Comment: Did you implemented sort through Joomla sorting mechanism?

Comment: Yes,I used joomla 2.5 documentation to develop my own component.

Comment: Are you using a class derived from `JModelList`? What do you have in your `populateState` method of your front-end model?

Comment: I derived my model class from JModelList.